# Shibboleth authentication with Angular and NGINX

Tags: angular, nginx, shibboleth

I have an Angular app that is authenticated by Shibboleth. When a user navigates to the page then NGINX redirects them to a Shibboleth login. Access to the app is managed by NGINX. If the users have logged in and got into the app they may be in there for a considerable time. The Shibboleth login times out but the Angular app doesn't know this and this causes problems with the services that the app has to communicate with.
How can I get Angular to check if Shibboleth is logged in?
Or (as a workaround) how do I force the browser to refresh (which causes NGINX to check the log in status) when a user clicks a submit button in order to use a service?

Thanks

Comment: Very few people know about Shibboleth authentication. Can you please explain about response of successful login. What they issue after login to authenticate request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting your question correct, 
You have an app https://example.com.

You have implemented SP on this side and protected - **authorized** whole web site - not any particular path. So whenever user visit the website, nginx goes to **authenticate** user to some IdP.

Now issue is, when you navigate in angular app, because of the pushState implementation, request does not go to nginx and thus you are not able to check whether user session is active or not.

If yes

Then I believe you will need to create an auth-gaurd in angular app, which checks the valid session on every page - the auth guard to be injected in every route.

You can check session validity by using following URLs,
https://example.com/Shibboleth.sso/Session
https://example.com/Shibboleth.sso/Status

Comment: That's just what I needed to know. I put in an auth-guard and used it to check the Shibboleth status. The app works perfectly now